# TestNG testcases not getting executed

Tags: testng

I have a test market with @Test annotaion. But when I run the test case, it shows me that
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
I am running test cases from within eclipse. I have testng plugin installed in eclipse.

TestClass Code:

```
 public class ModelledEventBus  {

        ModelledEventBusOperator dummyOperator = new ModelledEventBusOperator();

        /**
         * Dummy Test Case to show the interworkings of TAF classes
         */
        @VUsers(vusers = { 1, 10, 100 })
        @Test(dataProvider = "dummyTestData", dataProviderClass = ModelledEventBusTestDataProvider.class)
        public void dummyTestCase(String stringToPrint) {
            setTestcase("TC-DUMMY", "Dummy Test Case");
            setTestInfo("Testing " + stringToPrint);
            assertEquals(dummyOperator.operate(stringToPrint),
                    dummyOperator.expected());
        }
}
```

attributes inside @Test are custom.

```
public class ModelledEventBusTestDataProvider {



    // Dummy Test Data Provider Code generated to show interworkings of TAF Classes
    @DataProvider(name="dymmyTestData")
    public static String[][] dummyTestData(){
            String[][] result = {{"First String"},{"Second String"}};
            return result;
    }

}
```

TestNG version:6.8.0

Comment: show ur code..and how are you running it (right click run as testng?)  what version of testng plugin?

Comment: Hi niharika_neo, I have edited the question to add the details. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: can you also put the code for the dataprovider.

Comment: Hi niharika_neo, I have edited the question to add the DataProvider. Please let me know if you need any more details

Comment: I did try your code out, it works for me.  Can you increase the verbosity level and check.

Comment: Thanks  niharika_neo, for verbosity level tip!

Answer (score 0):

Your dataprovider name has a typo.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "dummyTestData", dataProviderClass = ModelledEventBusTestDataProvider.class)
        public void dummyTestCase(String stringToPrint) {

 @DataProvider(name="dymmyTestData")
    public static String[][] dummyTestData(){
```

One is d**u**mmyTestData and other d**y**mmyTestData.

Comment: Not sure whether its related to the version, I get an error when the names doesnt match.     SKIPPED: test1
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method public void dataprovidertest.test1(java.lang.String) requires a @DataProvider named : TestData in class Class5

Comment: oh not sure about that..mine is at 6.8

Answer (score 0):

I created the suite.xml file and it is running now. I am not quite sure what exactly the problem was, but I have a running test case now.

Comment: I actually tried without my suite xml too and that also was workin just fine with the same version as u have.. Hmm strange.  :)